# HTML images not aligning properly when retrieving data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I've been making a little league of legends website that uses Riot API to retrieve the mastery tree and displays the images. I've have three divs wrapped in another div, and all the images align correctly except for the last 2 rows of each div, and I can't figure out why. It must be something to do with how I am handling the rows with null in them. I've also noticed that the rows seem to want to self-align themselves (figured this out by not handling the null values), so maybe it's something inherent with divs. I can't link the site because I haven't secured my api key, so here's a picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/as5Bi.png

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
        <div id="Offense_page" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; float: left; border: 5px solid white;">Offense</div>
        <div id="Defense_page" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; float: left; border: 5px solid white;">Defense</div>
        <div id="Utility_page" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; float: left; border: 5px solid white;">Utility</div>
    </div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: url_tree,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {

                },
                success: function (json) {
                    test_id = "";
                    space = false;
                    pages = ["Offense", "Defense", "Utility"];
                    lengths = [json.tree.Offense.length, json.tree.Defense.length, json.tree.Utility.length];


                    for (i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) { //for each page
                        test_id = "";
                        space = false;
                        for (x = 0; x < lengths[i]; x++) {  //for the length of each page object
                            for (n = 0; n < json.tree.Offense[x].masteryTreeItems.length; n++) { // for the length of each Items object
                                if (json.tree[pages[i]][x].masteryTreeItems[n] != null && json.tree[pages[i]][x].masteryTreeItems[n] != "") {
                                    if (space) {
                                        test_id += "<img style=\"opacity: 1.0; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px; margin-left: 74px;\" src=http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.20.1/img/mastery/" + json.tree[pages[i]][x].masteryTreeItems[n].masteryId + ".png>";
                                        space = false;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        test_id += "<img style=\"opacity: 1.0; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 5px;\" src=http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/4.20.1/img/mastery/" + json.tree[pages[i]][x].masteryTreeItems[n].masteryId + ".png>";
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    space = true;
                                }
                            }
                            test_id += "<br />";
                        }
                        document.getElementById(pages[i] + "_page").innerHTML = test_id;

                    }
                }

            });
```

And Here is the JSON data that I'm pulling from: http://pastebin.com/DAAtukg4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have given `text-align:center` to some parent div.

Change from `text-align:center` to `text-align:left`. Perhaps, this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Nice!, I didn't even think about a parent div being the problem, stupid mistake.